# Grouping of Drop down list menu in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

Is there a way to group the selectOptions list values on a visualforce page?

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)?  There's [an idea for optgroup support](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000007PfYAAU).

Answer (score 0):

Trying rolling your own HTML using `optgroup` and then set your Controller parameter using JavaScript.

If the above seems too vague, check out the "possible duplicate" suggestion:  [Is there a way to group options in a selectList](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21120/is-there-a-way-to-group-options-in-a-selectlist)